# Can't View result while joining 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have some trouble when I Joining 3 tables, I use mysqli procedural. here's my query..

```
$select = $connection->conn->query('SELECT * FROM master_beli, supplier, karyawan WHERE supplier.id_supplier = master_beli.id_supplier AND karyawan.id_karyawan = master_beli.id_karyawan');
```

After that I viewing with this code

```
while($fetchData = $select->fetch_array()){
   echo $fetchData['id_karyawan'].'<br>';
}
```

I don't know where the problem is, because I use this query a few months ago and it's worked, but now isn't work..

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  master_beli.id_supplier,master_beli.id_karyawan
 FROM master_beli
 join supplier  on supplier.id_supplier = master_beli.id_supplier
 join karyawan on karyawan.id_karyawan = master_beli.id_karyawan;
```

it work on mysql

Answer (score 0):

Could be your issue is related  to the ambiguity of the column name `id_karyawan` present in two tables  try use an explicit alias or a explict column naming eg :

```
$select = $connection->conn->query('SELECT master_beli.id_karyawan
      FROM master_beli
      INNER JOIN supplier ON supplier.id_supplier = master_beli.id_supplier 
      INNER JOIN karyawan ON  karyawan.id_karyawan = master_beli.id_karyawan');
```

and as suggested in the code above you should use explicit join sintax  ..for better readibilty 
 (the use of implict join sintax  is not more promoted  in sql)